# Delete All files except specific file in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to use `rm -rf !(current)` delete all folders in current path except `current` folder.
But I am getting below error

> bash: !: event not found

How do I get this functionality in bash?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081379/using-find-to-delete-all-files-with-a-given-name-except-the-one-with-a-given-ext

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable `extglob`.

Suppose that we have three directories:

```
$ ls -d */
current/  future/  past/
```

Without extended glob, the following is not understood:

```
$ echo !(current)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

If we enable `extglob`, then it is understood:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo !(current)
future past
```

This successfully matches all files *except* `current`.

Note that the  exclamation point, `!`, is a bash-active character.  It can invoke history expansion which, if it fails, results in the error that you observed.  If you are not using history expansion, you may want to turn it off: `set +H`.

Comment: I am using history expansion. How do I use the same command without conflicting that